# Telethon send messages to multiple groups (wait of xxx seconds required in some groups)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Here is code that sending messages to all groups I'm in.

```
groups = []
async for dialog in client1.iter_dialogs():
    if(dialog.id < 0):
            print(dialog.name)
            groups.append(dialog.id)
print(groups)      
for group in groups:
    try:
        await client1.send_file(group, 'pic1.jpg')
        print("message sent to group" + str(group))
    except Exception as er:
        print(er)
```

For some reason on one account logs look like this

[image]

And on another account:
[image]

What's the difference between two. Why do I need to wait on one but not on other?

Answer (score 1):

That's floodwait. You can't send too many requests to the api at same time. It's telegram limitations. Nothing much telethon could do.

Comment: Yeah, but why on one account everything is fine and on another I get this floodwait?

Comment: That is not related to Telethon most prolly it's related to telegram. Telethon can't do much to avoid it